# invalid cast from void(WINAPI*)(...) to LPVOID

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, visual-c++, qt5

i'm trying to use this code [RasDialAsync.c] (https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/blob/master/netds/ras/rasdialasync/RasDialAsync.c) inside QT , i have only one error that i can't figure it out . what is this ? how can i fix this ? here is the function header : 

My RasDialFunc function :

```
void WINAPI RasDialFunc(UINT unMsg,
                    RASCONNSTATE rasconnstate,
                    DWORD dwError )
```

and here is part of my codes :

```
LPRASDIALPARAMS lpRasDialParams = NULL;   // Structure to store the RasDial parameters
HRASCONN        hRasConn = NULL;          // Handle to RAS connection
DWORD           nRet = 0;                 // Return value from a function
lpRasDialParams = (LPRASDIALPARAMS) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(RASDIALPARAMS));
if (NULL == lpRasDialParams)
{
    qDebug() << "HeapAlloc failed\n";
}
lpRasDialParams->dwSize =sizeof(RASDIALPARAMS);
StringCchCopy(lpRasDialParams->szEntryName, CELEMS(lpRasDialParams->szEntryName), rasConn);
StringCchCopy(lpRasDialParams->szUserName, CELEMS(lpRasDialParams->szUserName), username);
StringCchCopy(lpRasDialParams->szPassword, CELEMS(lpRasDialParams->szPassword), password);

hRasConn = NULL;
nRet = RasDial(NULL, NULL, lpRasDialParams, 0,&RasDialFunc, &hRasConn);
if (nRet != 0)
```

and here is the error

```
main.cpp:202: error: invalid conversion from 'void (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(UINT, tagRASCONNSTATE, DWORD) {aka void (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(unsigned int, tagRASCONNSTATE, long unsigned int)}' to 'LPVOID {aka void*}' [-fpermissive]
     nRet = RasDial(NULL, NULL, lpRasDialParams, 0,&RasDialFunc, &hRasConn);
                                                                          ^
```

Comment: static_cast<void*>(&RasDialFunc)

Comment: @Olipro same error : invalid cast ....

Comment: We can't see the declaration for `RasDial()`. This is required information.

Comment: @IInspectable It's [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377004.aspx), I presume.

Comment: @IInspectable [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377004(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: It is, technically, illegal to cast between a function pointer and an object pointer. The standard allows them to have different sizes. For better or worse, WinAPI requires such a cast in a number of places (and I seem to recall there are some POSIX functions that do, too). MSVC compiler never complained about such a cast, but you are using GCC, which seems to want to be pedantic about it. I suspect there's might be some command line option that would make GCC accept it - look for that (I myself am not familiar with GCC).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so if i use msvc it should be gone ?

Comment: I'm 99% sure it would compile with MSVC. 99.9% if you use `static_cast`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes with msvc everything works fine so is there any way to use gcc instead msvc

Comment: Well, the error message suggests `-fpermissive` command line option. Have you tried that? Like I said, I know very little about GCC beyond the fact that it exists.

Comment: What about reinterpret_cast ?

Comment: @E4z9 thanks , that work's perfectly .

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you Man .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These Following Comments are my answer :

> It is, technically, illegal to cast between a function pointer and an
>   object pointer. The standard allows them to have different sizes. For
>   better or worse, WinAPI requires such a cast in a number of places
>   (and I seem to recall there are some POSIX functions that do, too).
>   MSVC compiler never complained about such a cast, but you are using
>   GCC, which seems to want to be pedantic about it. I suspect there's
>   might be some command line option that would make GCC accept it - look
>   for that (I myself am not familiar with GCC). – [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik)

> reinterpret_cast - [E4z9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6624417/e4z9)

And the final code is  :

```
    nRet = RasDial(NULL, NULL, lpRasDialParams, 0,reinterpret_cast<void*>(&RasDialFunc) , &hRasConn);
```